# Names of the C family of languages

Tags: c, programming-languages

Why is the C language called "C"? Does C stand for "Compiler"?

Also, why does C++ have two pluses? Is it because it is the second version of C? What about C#, does the `#` stand for four pluses (`++++`)? Is there going to be something else in the future, something like C~ or C*?

Comment: I fail to understand why this question was voted down.

Comment: "C" in C programming language means "Code" && "Compile", both of which are essential and core fundamental of programming :-) That's why C becomes the grand grand root of nearly all mainstream programming languages :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this page of programming language name origins](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?ProgrammingLanguageNamingPatterns). Note that various names like C, C++, and C# were made up by different people over time, so who can say what someone will choose in the future?

Answer (score 7):

the languages are named after their predecessor languages

C is the successor to B.

C++ means "increment C by 1" in C

C# (sharp, not pound) means a half-note above C (from music)

Comment: You might add that B was a successor to (and subset of) BCPL. There was once some discussion whether the _next_ language after C would be D or P, settled by the C++ pun. Note also that D is a language in the family too...

Answer (score 3):

C++ is not the second version of C. C++ tried to add classes, templates and a few more things.

Quote from Wikipedia regarding the naming of C++:

> According to Stroustrup: "the name
>   signifies the evolutionary nature of
>   the changes from C".[5] During C++'s
>   development period, the language had
>   been referred to as "new C", then "C
>   with Classes". The final name is
>   credited to Rick Mascitti (mid-1983)
>   and was first used in December 1983.
>   When Mascitti was questioned
>   informally in 1992 about the naming,
>   he indicated that it was given in a
>   tongue-in-cheek spirit. It stems from
>   C's "++" operator (which increments
>   the value of a variable) and a common
>   naming convention of using "+" to
>   indicate an enhanced computer program.
>   There is no language called "C plus".
>   ABCL/c+ was the name of an earlier,
>   unrelated programming language.

Answer (score 3):

C is after B, which was a condensed BCPL. It was a natural progression of names. The ++ is a common programming operator which means "increment by one."

Comment: Almost. B came from BCPL. C was the obvious successor.

Comment: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html

Well according to this, the sequence was BCPL->B->C. B just wasn't around very long. (I was going off of memory when I wrote my answer. )

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time there was a language called BCPL. BCPL begot B, which begot C. C begot C++, an incremental improvement. C# is pretty unlike C++ or C save perhaps for the basics of the syntax, but the sharp is a "visual pun" on a second set of pluses.

```
  ++
  ++   ~ #
```

Comment: Except that people who came up with it in the first place disagree with you (http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/CNETHistoryLesson.aspx). It means exactly what it means - C-sharp - that is, half a tone higher than C.

Comment: Sorry, if I implied it was pronounced C++++, it's definitely "C-sharp". But the gag is it's four pluses.

Comment: Incidentally, James Kovacs did not create C#, or if he did, he's neglected to mention the fact. He also, as far as I can tell, doesn't currently work for Microsoft, and I can't find a resume to determine whether he did in the past, he may have, but I suspect not.